# Does a term or expression exist for the phenomenon where a person treats unclear future risk as non-important?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Does a term or expression exist for the phenomenon where a person treats unclear future risk as non-important? As in:

> I will ignore the coronavirus threat because I'm unlikely to contract it or get severely ill.
>
> I will eat unhealthy because whether or not I will get ill is unclear.

Comment: Do you require a label for the phenomenon, or will descriptions of people exemplifying it ('irresponsible', 'devil-may-care', 'feckless', 'imprudent', 'incautious', 'uncircumspect', 'foolhardy' + other synonyms) do? 'Shortsighted' and 'blinkered' are also possibilities.

Comment: It's likely that the answers here will be almost exactly those at the [Is there a single word for doing something despite the fact that it might cause problems later?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/464541/is-there-a-single-word-for-doing-something-despite-the-fact-that-it-might-cause/468713#468713) thread, though the question is very slightly different.

Comment: ...apart from "being very young"?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth good observation, speficially interested whether a good word exists for the phenomenom itself, not the descriptions concerning people.

Comment: You probably need to stress the 'about a possible future catastrophe', and even refine it to 'about a possible future catastrophe that many are saying is a very grave risk', or you'll end up with 'imprudence' or 'incaution' ('[noun]: 
failure to heed potential problems or risks': [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/incaution)).

Answer (score 1):

They are happy-go-lucky, and possibly short-lived.

Cambridge Dictionary: [Happy-go-lucky](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/happy-go-lucky)

> A happy-go-lucky person does not plan much and accepts what happens without becoming worried.

Answer (score 0):

That can be defined as ***reckless***  behavior.

[Merriam Webster defines it](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reckless) as:

> marked by lack of proper caution : careless of consequences

Comment: One could describe someone who does not worry about an 'unclear future risk' as merely 'confident'. Reckless people flout clear, present risks.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - I completely agree. An astronaut might completely ignore it and be perfectly reasonable.  OP’s examples are not consistent, but I tried to answer in the spirit in which I believe the question was asked.

Comment: The OP's examples are, indeed, not consistent, either with the 'spirit' of the question, or with each other. Coronavirus is a clear, present, proven risk, and the matter of whether some food is 'unhealthy' is to some extent a matter of opinion.  I believe a close vote is needed.