# I need help to find a word that's too long to describe in a title

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

Is there a word for a group of people that know they're doing something wrong, but they don't want to stop in fear of embarrassing themselves or letting their peers down? An example sentence would be

- It's no use trying to reason with them – they're all just [...]s."

Comment: Welcome to ELU, a67832492. Could you provide an example sentence that demonstrates how the word would be used?

Comment: "It's no use to reason with them, they're all just (word)s."

Comment: Peer-pressured?

Comment: I like the word "peer-pressured" but I feel there might be a better option.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Idiom for doing something intentionally despite knowing the outcome might be bad](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/272933/idiom-for-doing-something-intentionally-despite-knowing-the-outcome-might-be-bad)

Comment: At the duplicate, 'lemmings', 'conformists' and 'sheeple' are given. 'Robots' is implied.

Answer (score 0):

One might “[follow the crowd](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/follow-the-crowd)”.

To fit in your example sentence:

> “It’s no use to reason with them; they’re all just crowd followers.”

Comment: Notice that this is a single-word-request. There have been many threads with 'follow the crowd' suggested as an answer.

Comment: If it’s absolutely imperative you use one word, I'd argue "follower" works.